# How do I link a function to a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, I made a "love calculator" code and it's working but I want to give it a GUI. I want when I click on the button a number shows up under it. but I can't get it working. I really need help. I'm using python 3.8 with Tkinter. I want when I click on the button. I get an error that l1 is not defined. If you can please help because I'm an absolute beginner to Pyhton.
Here is the code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from random import*




def get_love():
      name1 = entry1.get()
      name2 = entry2.get() 
      if (len(name1)) - (len(name2))== 2 or 1 or 0 or -1 or -2 or -3: 
         l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Here is how much you love eachother:  ", (randint(40, 100)), '%')
      else:
        l2 = tk.Label(root, "Here is how much you love eachother:  ", (randint(0, 49)), '%')






root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Love Calculator")
root.minsize(600, 600)
root.configure(background = 'pink')


w = tk.Label(root, bg="pink",font="Times 32 bold", text="Welcome to Love Calculator")
w1 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink",font="Arial 20", text=" ")


w2 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", fg="white" ,font="Arial 19", text="Write your name here")
entry1 = tk.Entry (root)

w10 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink",font="Arial 20", text=" ")

w3 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", fg="white" ,font="Arial 19", text="Write your lover's name here")
entry2 = tk.Entry (root)










b = Button(root, text="Click to see how much you love each other", font='Times 20 bold', command=get_love)





w.pack()
w1.pack()
w2.pack()
entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
w3.pack()
w10.pack()
b.pack()
l1.pack()
l2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First of all: Hello! You can use e.g. lambda functionality of python

Comment: i really dont know what you are talking about. can you please give me further detail.

Comment: lambda is pythons inline function definition keyword (spoken as easy as possible) - with them you can pass on a function to your command
in your case somthing like command= lambda: get_love() - its a cool feature check out its functionality ;)

Comment: As an aside, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **complete guide** for you to **fix your issue** with only a **few simple changes**.

---

There are **three** simple **problems** with your program:

---

**Problem 1:**

You are using `or` in a wrong way so the condition(`if`) always returns `True` and the `else` block never gets executed, Here:

```
    if (len(name1)) - (len(name2)) == 2 or 1 or 0 or -1 or -2 or -3:
```

**Solution:**

You can use `range` to solve this issue. You have to give it two numbers keeping in mind that the second number won't be included in the range, Like this:

```
    if (len(name1)) - (len(name2)) in range(-3, 3):
```

---

**Problem 2:**

You are doing a mistake in the string concatenation, Here:

```
    text="Here is how much you love each other:  ", (randint(40, 100)), '%')
```

**Solution:**

There are **two** possible **solutions** for this problem:

1. You can use the plus "+" symbol instead of commas in it, Like this:

```
    text="Here is how much you love each other: " + str(randint(40, 100)) + '%'
```

But as you can see, then you will also have to convert the random integer`(randint(40, 100))` to a string, Like this: **`str`**`(randint(40, 100))`

2. The easiest solution to this problem is to use a formatted string, Like this:

```
    text=f"Here is how much you love each other: {(randint(40, 100))}%"
```

---

**Problem 3:**

The **main reason** for getting the error is that you have defined your labels(`l1` and `l2`) inside a function(`get_love()`), And you are trying to `pack()` these labels outside the function.

**Solution:**

The solution is to remove the `pack()` from outside the function for both labels(`l1` and `l2`), and `pack()` them inside the function right after defining them. Like This:

```
def get_love():

    name1 = entry1.get()
    name2 = entry2.get()

    if (len(name1)) - (len(name2)) == 2 or 1 or 0 or -1 or -2 or -3:
        l1 = tk.Label(root, text=f"Here is how much you love each other: {(randint(40, 100))}%")
        l1.pack()

    else:
        l2 = tk.Label(root, text=f"Here is how much you love each other: {(randint(0, 49))}%")
        l2.pack()
```

---

### Complete Fixed Code:

**Here is the complete fixed code for you:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import *


def get_love():

    name1 = entry1.get()
    name2 = entry2.get()

    if (len(name1)) - (len(name2)) in range(-3, 3):
        l1 = tk.Label(root, text=f"Here is how much you love each other: {(randint(40, 100))}%")
        l1.pack()

    else:
        l2 = tk.Label(root, text=f"Here is how much you love each other: {(randint(0, 49))}%")
        l2.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Love Calculator")
root.minsize(600, 600)
root.configure(background='pink')


w = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", font="Times 32 bold", text="Welcome to Love Calculator")
w1 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", font="Arial 20", text=" ")


w2 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", fg="white", font="Arial 19", text="Write your name here")
entry1 = tk.Entry(root)

w10 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", font="Arial 20", text=" ")

w3 = tk.Label(root, bg="pink", fg="white", font="Arial 19", text="Write your lover's name here")
entry2 = tk.Entry(root)


b = tk.Button(root, text="Click to see how much you love each other", font='Times 20 bold', command=get_love)


w.pack()
w1.pack()
w2.pack()
entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
w3.pack()
w10.pack()
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `(len(name1)) - (len(name2)) == 2 or 1 or 0 or -1 or -2 or -3` will always return `True` since this is improper use of `or`.

Comment: @tgikal I don't think it will return `True` all the time, Let's say if the difference between the length of the two strings(`name1` and `name2`) is more than three, then it would return `False`. It could be done better by using `range` but I kept it the same so the OP of the question has to make as fewer changes as possible.

Comment: No with `or 1` in the statement, it will always be true. This can easily be tested with `False == True or True`. `or` does not evaluate other cases, it evaluates other statements, you would have to test the value to each case between the `or`'s to work correctly.

Comment: @tgikal Thank you very much sir, I have now updated my Answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe a lambda is needed here, simply use the `if/else` to generate the number then format it into the label text.

Python has a nice feature for testing if a number is between two values: `if -3 <= x <= 2`

Also, avoid pitfalls like using numbers as variables, and importing things multiple times (import tkinter as tk, from tkinter import *)

For labels that are never going to change you don't need to store them to a variable, just pack/grid/place them as-is.

If you just need a space on the window add padding to an existing widget, or use a grid layout.

These are all just suggestions to hopefully help.

I did a bunch of code cleanup here:

```
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk

def get_love():
    name1 = entry1.get()
    name2 = entry2.get() 
    if -3 <= (len(name1) - len(name2)) <= 2:
        number = randint(40, 100)
    else:
        number = randint(0, 49)
    display.config(text="Here is how much you love eachother: {}%".format(number))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Love Calculator")
root.minsize(600, 600)
root.configure(background = 'pink')

tk.Label(root, bg="pink",font="Times 32 bold",
         text="Welcome to Love Calculator").pack(pady = (0, 20))

tk.Label(root, bg="pink", fg="white", font="Arial 19",
         text="Write your name here").pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack()

tk.Label(root, bg="pink", fg="white",font="Arial 19",
         text="Write your lover's name here").pack(pady = (0, 20))

tk.Button(root, text="Click to see how much you love each other",
          font='Times 20 bold', command=get_love).pack(pady = (0, 20))

display = tk.Label(root, bg="pink")
display.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are the best in the world but i have a lil problem. how can I restart the code after clicking on the button because whenever i click it again it shows up another time under the last one